# Operating systems which have non-x86 instruction set architecture

Tags: hardware, emulation, operating-system, instruction-set

What are the most famous operating systems for non-x86 computers? I mean, most famous OS which have different instruction set architecture.

**Background** (to better understand my task):

I ask this question because currently I working on a paper which describes the difference between hypervisors and emulators. It have a passage which looks like:

> You could install Windows 95 on Windows 7 with *hypervisor*, but you cannot install <...> on Windows 7, because these operating systems are developed to use different instructions sets. You will need *emulator* for it.

"<...>" is the name of OS which I ask for.

Comment: I wouldn't like to see this sentence in a cs paper. this is probably for a "background" section, so just explain, what a hypervisor *does* and that a direct consequence is that guest operating systems must target the host's architecture / instruction set... that said, nowadays, there's arguably no "famous" OS that doesn't have an x86 port. Back then, there would be many, e.g. all these 68k systems (classic MacOS, AmigaOS, etc).

Comment: But then, this question doesn't really seem to be about retrocomputing *at all* :o

Comment: @FelixPalmen "at all" - well, probably. Some questions should be answered, but it is very hard to decide where to find people who really understand them..

Comment: This is way too broad to be useful as the simple short answer is that almost all operating systems do not use an x86 architecture.  x86 is a small minority in terms of type.

Comment: The question have -3 votes and closed. I agree, the question is bad, but answers and further discussion are great. That's why **I hope it will not be removed from site.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Too long for a comment, sorry)*

This question is **way** too broad to give any serious answer (beside collecting meetoos with whatever favorite OS).

I suggest you go for [Wikis OS list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems) (which is non exhaustive anyway) and pick some random.

And then there is maybe a *tiny* misconception in your assumption. Installing an OS is not *only* an issue of an instruction set, but a machine structure as well (if not more).

- An OS made for some non-IBM-PC x86 computer will as well not boot under a Hypervisor providing a PC-type virtual environment
- As an OS for a exact PC style hardware using a non x86 CPU won't either.
- And even more, an OS requiring a 'newer' version of a x86 will as well not work.

A further misconception could be that a Hypervisor does not do emulation. But isn't that the whole point? It emulates certain devices for each guest and then merges the results into a real one (think Disk or Network). Similar, many provide emulation layers to present a certain hardware as some other, maybe more simple type. Think a NE2000 hardware level emulation when the actual network interface is a total different one.

---

P.S.: Somewhat unrelated, but maybe helpful: If you have to write a paper, you should only use analogies that you can defend on your own. *'the internet said'* doesn't always work well.

Comment: Great answer. "A further misconception could be that a Hypervisor does not do emulation." As I understand:

Comment: **1st point:** Virtualization is a process of _separating_ resources, while emulation is the process of _imitating_ resources (this is how most people talk about it).

Comment: **2nd Point:** [Hypervisor do virtualization on hardware-abstraction-level, while emulator do virtualization at instruction-set-architecture-level.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/82cc/c92ec746352d529afc18815db36a4167697a.pdf)

Comment: **3rd point:** As a consequence from 1st point - that's why we can "fake" RAM and HDD size with hypervisor, but we will need emulator to imitate the CPU cycles.

Comment: **4th point:** As a consequence from 1st and 2nd points, there is some mess in terminology. Actually, hypervisor and emulator do the same thing - virtualization, but at the different levels.

Comment: **Question from 4th point:** So, is it correct to call emulators "low-level hypervisors"?

Comment: ... Or, probably, we should talk about hypervisors as a high-level emulators (looks more correctly at my opinion)

Comment: "*A further misconception could be that a Hypervisor does not do emulation*" <- this is, in fact, true. The hypervisor, at its core, *doesn't* do *any* emulation. Most hypervisors come *with* emulations of certain "peripherals" to enable some operating systems to run at all. But the goal is to eliminate this need -- instead, you try to provide lean interfaces for common classes of peripherals (like gfx, network, storage) and load appropriate "drivers" for these in the guest OS, see for example "virtio".

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well, that is about as meaningful as saying _'Some DOS come with drivers for disks'_ isn't it`? After all, the whole purpose of a Hypervisor is emulation. It offers each guest an emulation of a virtual machine.

Comment: @Raffzahn no, the purpose is virtualization. Emulation should be avoided as much as possible. Packaging emulation for some things (like e.g. often an ahci-conforming disk controller) is only done as a last resort for guest OS' that don't have the necessary support for e.g. a virtio block device.

Comment: @FelixPalmen you're aware that your argumentation is cyclic? What's purpose might be fine, but what counts is what is implemented. Ans sure, it is a must to keep the emulated part down to a minimum. But Virtualisation is per se emulation. Even if moved down to hardware level. Also, don't focus so much on modern PC - virtualization is wy older and originated in 80s mainframes (thats where I played with it first) And even there, where the whole software structure is extreme modular and abstract, a hypervisor did include some emulation to work on real hardware, not just optional add ons.

Comment: @Raffzahn So, it seems you agree with my statements above?

Comment: @Raffzahn how is this "cyclic"? Emulation has always been a necessary evil when virtualizing hardware, but has been greatly reduced nowadays. You say "*Virtualisation is per se emulation.*" and this is wrong. Without hardware support, you needed to emulate an MMU -- but this emulation didn't "move to hardware", it was rendered unnecessary by hardware directly supporting virtualization. With a type-1 hypervisor and guest systems fully supporting it, you can have "emulation-free" virtualization.

Comment: @johnc.j. Yes, I do. Except I wouldn't call it different levels, as that includes the image of stacking on on each other. I would rather go for 'emulation to different extend' as in what components are emulated to what extend. Also, virtualisation is in some extend different from simple emulation, as it contains a component of multiplication. But I guess that's a philosophical issue to define when this sets on.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I guess you're right, and I simply don't nderstand that moving some function into hardware is something totally different than hardware suporting that function ... Must be a cool world.

Comment: @Raffzahn you were talking about "moving emulation to hardware", which is a contradiction in itself.

Comment: @Raffzahn Hello and happy New Year :) Could you elaborate please, what you mean under "machine structure"? As I understand, you mean microarchitecture (also known as "computer organization"). Right? But on the other hand, according to Wikipedia, the computer architecture consists of **three** (not two!) main aspects: 1) instruction set architecture, 2) microarhitecture, and 3) system design. Does system design has some impact when we use a hypervisor to run one OS on top of another?

Comment: @johnc.j. Machine structure is to mean everything past the CPU. What interfaces are present, at what addresses, how they are to be handled, this includes as well memory. A hypervisor, like any other OS is fited to a certain machine or group of compatible machines. Thus it will not run on machines not build the way it expects. Much the same way as a OS under a hypervisor will not run if the hypervisor doesn't present the machine as the OS expects it. Long story short, the question has been closed as it does not make sense in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

The most famous operating system which you can’t install on a non-binary-translating hypervisor in Windows is probably ... Windows, in one of its non-x86 incarnations (Windows CE, Windows RT, non-x86 Windows NT, or ARM64 Windows 10).

There are many other possibilities:

- one of the Unix versions or Unix-like systems on non-x86, going back to the original PDP-7 Unix;
- pre-x86 releases of OS X and MacOS, on PowerPC and Motorola 68k;
- VMS, on VAX systems;
- any of the mainframe or mini or (non-x86) super-computer operating systems;
- many micro operating systems, such as Atari TOS, AmigaOS...

These are just a few examples, there are hundreds of others. Determining which one of these is the most famous is probably a matter of context and opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some examples:

- AmigaOS
- [Classic Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS)
- [RISC OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS)

Comment: @UncleBod Sure. Also CP/M had a 68000 version as I recall.

Comment: @UncleBod I would argue that CP/M **did** have an x86 version. There was a very clear migration path (used by many applications - e.g., WordStar; and by many manufacturers) from 8-bit CP/M & MP/M to 16-bit CP/M-86 & MP/M-86.

Answer (score 2):

#### IBM OS/360

This is the system that led IBM to dominate the mainframe world. Succeeded by OS/370 and one could easily argue that the later dominance of Windows was a direct outgrowth of MS/PC-DOS dominance which in turn came from the IBM PC. The IBM PC was a largely mediocre machine but it was from IBM and that's what mattered most.